# LinkedIn API: simple link to follow company

Tags: jquery, linkedin-api

I'm working on a project where I need to create a link that when clicked, it takes the user to a LinkedIn profile and also automatically follows the company. I'm assuming the LinkedIn API is the way to go for this but I'm a little stuck; I've gone through the steps of creating a new application and have successfully created a login button based on the documentation but I'm a little confused as to how to create just a single link that I could wrap around an image. Is this ultimately what the examples in the docs create? Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can build a Follow Company plugin from here:
https://developer.linkedin.com/plugins/follow-company

The plugin is documented here:
https://developer.linkedin.com/follow-company

Answer (score 0):

seems like LinkedIn wants to keep their brand identity so their API pretty much is restricted to giving you a button .. of which there are many varieties to choose from:  https://developer.linkedin.com/plugins/follow-company

However, with some CSS you can style this to look however you want.  Keep in mind that you will want to keep within the parameters in the license agreement: http://developer.linkedin.com/linkedin-plugins-license-agreement